# Proving Baby Rudin's Exercise 21 Chapter 3

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am trying to prove:

> If $\{E_n\}$ is a sequence of closed, nonempty, and bounded sets in a complete metric space $X$, if $E_n \supset E_{n+1}$, and if $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \textrm{ diam } E_n = 0,$$ then $\cap_{1}^{\infty} E_n$ consists of exactly one point.

Here is my attempt:

**Proof**: Suppose $\{E_n\}$ is a sequence of closed, nonempty, and bounded sets in a complete metric space $X$ such that $E_n \supset E_{n+1}$ and
\begin{equation}\label{21.1}
    \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \textrm{ diam } E_n = 0
\end{equation}
Denote $E = \cap_{1}^{\infty} E_n$. Suppose to the contrary that $E$ does not contain exactly one point. Then, either $E$ contains more that one point or is empty. If $E$ contains more that one point, then $\textrm{ diam } E > 0$. But, for each $n$, $E_n \supset E$, so that $\textrm{ diam } E_n \geq \textrm{ diam } E > 0$ which contradicts $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \textrm{ diam } E_n = 0$. This shows that $\left|E\right|\leq 1$.

<s>If $E$ is empty, then each non-empty $E_1, E_2, \dots$ must be mutually disjoint. This contradicts $E_n \supset E_{n+1}$ and we are done.</s>

My question: I never used the fact that $X$ is a complete metric space and that each $E_n$ is nonempty and bounded. This makes me think that there is something wrong with my proof. Can someone please let me know what's wrong with my proof?

Now, construct a sequence $\{p_n\}$ such that $$p_1, \in E_1, p_2, \in E_2, \dots .$$ We know that each $p_n$ exists since each $E_n$ is non-empty. Further, we claim that $\{p_n\}$ is Cauchy in $X$.

[Some argument that involves $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \textrm{ diam } E_n = 0$, perhaps, which proves that $\{p_n\}$ is indeed Cauchy in $X$.]

Since $X$ is complete, $\exists p \in X$ such that $\{p_n\} \to p$. Since each $E_n$ is complete, $p \in E_n$ for each $n$, that is, $p \in E$. This shows that $\left|E\right|\geq 1 \implies \left|E\right| =  1$.

**My question**: How can I prove that $\{p_n\}$ is Cauchy? Thanks!

Comment: Your second part ("If $E$ is empty...") needs more justification.

Comment: What is your justification for the assertion that if $E$ is empty, then $E_i$ must be mutually disjoint? Completeness certainly plays a role as the following shows.  Consider $E_n=[r-\frac{1}{n}, r+\frac{1}{n}]\subset\mathbb{Q}$ where $r$ is irrational.

Comment: It is hard to imagine $E_{i}$ and $E_{i+1}$ are disjoint since $E_{i+1} \subset E_{i}$. Rather try to show that any sequence $\{a_i\}$ with $a_i \in E_i$ must be Cauchy and make an educated guess as to where the limit is.

Comment: Note that $p_n, p_{n+1}, p_{n+2}, \ldots$ all belong to $E_n$. What does that tell you about $d(p_k,p_m)$ for $k,m \geqslant n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Daniel Fisher's and @TSU's comments:

Proving that $\{p_n\}$ is Cauchy in $X$:
Notice that $p_n, p_{n+1}, \dots$ all belong to the set $E_n$. Without loss of generality, assume that $p_b, p_c \in E_n$ are such that $b , c \geq n$ and $\textrm{diam } E_n = d(p_b, p_c)$. Now, recall that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \textrm{ diam } E_n = 0$ which means that for all $\epsilon > 0$
\begin{equation*}
    n \geq N \implies d(p_b, p_c) < \epsilon
\end{equation*}
Here, we have shown that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b , c \geq n \geq N \implies d(p_b, p_c) < \epsilon$ by the definition of the diameter of $E_n$. This shows that $\{p_n\}$ is Cauchy in $X$.